# How to start and Bid Port 8080 to be able accessed by Oracle in browser - 127.0.0.1:8080

Tags: browser, oracle11g, port, listener, netstat

I need your help.

So, I Installed an **Oracle 11G R2 Express Edition**. But when I tried to open the **Database Home Page** in    **//localhost:8080/apex/**    or
 **//127.0.0.1:8080/apex/**, I always got error mssg on my browser (I Used Google  Chrome and Baidu Browser).

[Here is the Error Msg Pic on Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaYkm.png) And 
[This one also.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gt3x.png)

I had tried running this code on my **Sql Command Line**

```
connect system
begin 
dbms_xdb.sethttpport('8181'); 
end; 
/
Press enter
```

And tried to access **://localhost:8181/apex/** on my browser, but there is no change.

I checked all the listener port with ***netstat -a***  And find out that [there is no port 8080 as The Listener/ NO **127.0.0.1:8080**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmyiK.png).

Then I checked my ***Listener Status*** and got [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udUva.png)

Based on the **Listener Status** and List of listener port got by ***netstat -a***, I tried access **http://0.0.0.0:1521/apex/** on my Chrome browser. [GOT THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8yfi.png)

I really have no Idea what should I do. I had read and tried many, but no change at all.. Please if somebody here can help me solve this problem. I would thank and appriciate for all the helper so much..

Do I need to instal XAMPP?

I had turned on / off my firewall from control panel. But there's also no change. Should it be ON / OFF?

Note :

- Im using Windows 7 - 32 Bit
- Plese give the answer with the detailed steps, as Im not really good about 
  computer and A new comer in Oracle.

Thanks

Comment: The (TNS) listener port has nothing to do with web access. The 0.0.0.0 means something is listening to the specified port on all the machine's IP addresses, rather than a specific one (like localhost, 127.0.0.1). You can't connect to 0.0.0.0 directly. But it looks odd that `Fareham-PC` equates to 0.0.0.0, I'd expect that to be a LAN address - in your case that looks like 192.168.123.4. Is your hosts file configured with 127.0.0.1 listed against that hostname instead of localhost for some reason?

Comment: I had tried localhost (few months ago) when learn about website dev. And there was no problem to access the localhost / 126.0.0.1 from my browser. Then I re-installed my os and didnt install yet any xampp. Actually, before this error occured in browser when trying to access the localhost, The browser can load it succesfully. And there was also port 8080 listening when  running netstat -a, but then I tried to turn off the firewall and tried to change the port to be 8181 (dbms_xdb.sethttpport('8181');). Since that, this problem start. What should I do with this? What meaning of ur last sentence?

Comment: Do I need to install XAMPP? ( but I guess there is no rellation with this). And should I turn on / off my firewall regarding to this? As I read alot of article / discussion about this, mention alot this port listener and the windows firewall.

Comment: Here is my host file : # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
# 127.0.0.1       localhost
# ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1 validation.sls.microsoft.com